# Adding two urls to Facebook auth?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I'd like my app to work on both `sub.domain.com` and `sub1.domain.com` how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by specifying both sub domains or root domain in "App Domain" field in application settings (Basic Info section)